# Rubin's Rule of pooled confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, multiple-imputation, pooling

Rubin's Rule for multiple imputation states [that](https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/rubins-rules.html#confidence-intervals)

you are to construct a **single** interval **after** pooling into a single set of estimates and standard errors:

$$
\bar{\theta} \pm t_{df,1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}*SE_{Pooled}
$$

Is this fundamentally different than constructing CI for each imputation and pooling each bounds separately as arithmetic mean, something like below?

$$
\left[\frac{1}{m}\left(\sum_{i=1}^m LowerBound_i\right),
\frac{1}{m}\left(\sum_{i=1}^m UpperBound_i\right)\right]
$$

where $m$ is the number of imputations?

From the small dataset I had, the results seemed to be identical, at least up to a certain decimal point, but it could have been due to chance and I wish to make sure in theoretical standpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you write might come close in some circumstances but can't be counted on in general. For example, putting multiple imputation aside for a moment, an average of hazard-ratio confidence intervals from Cox survival regression models among bootstrapped samples from a complete data set will tend to be very poorly behaved.

For multiple imputation, Section 2.3 of Stef van Buuren's [Flexible Imputation of Missing Data](https://stefvanbuuren.name/fimd/sec-whyandwhen.html) explains that Rubin's Rules take not only within-imputation and between-imputation variances into account but also a further variance due to a finite number of imputations. The variance of an averaged statistic $\bar Q$ among $m$ imputations thus has three sources:

> The total variance [of $\bar Q$] stems from three sources:
>
> $\bar U$, the variance caused by the fact that we are taking a sample rather than observing the entire population. This is the conventional statistical measure of variability;
>
> $B$, the extra variance caused by the fact that there are missing values in the sample;
>
> $B/m$, the extra simulation variance caused by the fact that $\bar Q$ itself is estimated for finite $m$.
>
> The addition of the latter term is critical to make multiple imputation work at low values of $m$.

What you write seems to be most closely related to the variance contributed by $\bar U$, although it might include some contribution from $B$ insofar as the mean-value estimates change among imputation sets and thus shift the CI. It doesn't seem, however, to include the extra variance due to a finite value of $m$. If you had a large number $m$ of imputations that might not be a big problem.

So it's safest to follow Rubin's Rules and stick with the pooled SE.